# Vim copy one line and paste it to multiple lines

Tags: linux, macos, vim, macvim

I was sure I knew how to do it but I tried on different machines and it seems I don't know.

```
1 COPY THIS
2
3
4 HERE
5 HERE
```

So that it becomes

```
1 COPY THIS
2
3
4 COPY THIS
5 COPY THIS
```

What I tried: Shift-V on line 1 to copy line in visual mode, then go to line 4 visual mode vertical selection on lines 4 and 5. Now p to paste.

I was expecting to paste to both lines.

What happens: It paste to line 4 and line 5 gets deleted.

May I ask a friendly help here?

Comment: yank the word `COPYTHIS`   with `yiw`. Then make a visual selection  (`Ctrt+V`) of the text in lines 4 and 5 and paste with `p`.

Comment: same thing, it paste one line only

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You must paste twice: `2p` instead of `p`

also, if you only want to copy one line whole, you can skip the visual line and just use `yy`

and to eradicate the visualmode altogether do this:

```
:0
yy
:4
2dd
2"0p
```

which will do:

```
GOTO line 0
copy the current line
GOTO line 4
delete the following two lines (*)
twice: paste line from register 0
```

(*) note that the deletion overrides the entry in the default register.

See also [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26654/how-can-i-paste-overwriting-with-vim) on Unix.SE

Comment: It works. But am I wrong thinking visual selecting both lines should work?

Comment: @KcFnMi Yes, you are wrong in assuming that it should work. Visual selecting both lines just means: "Act on this area." It does not mean: "repeat everything that often"

Comment: @KcFnMi I'm fairly certain you could come up with a command that would do a command once for each newline in the visual area, but that would be odd. Keep in mind that a visual area does not need to cover lines at all but can be anywhere on a line as well.

Comment: Last question: Let's say, instead of yy, I copied a block with C-v. If I do 2p then it paste the block 2x, one after the other but in the same line. How do I paste 1x at each line? Might be another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017570/vim-copy-a-block-and-paste-it-to-multiple-lines#52017570.