# Vim copy a block and paste it to multiple lines

Tags: linux, macos, vim, macvim

I know I can `yy`on line 1 and then visual select lines 4 and 5 `2p`([Vim copy one line and paste it to multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016333/vim-copy-one-line-and-paste-it-to-multiple-lines)).

```
1 COPY THIS
2
3
4 HERE
5 HERE
```

So I get:

```
1 COPY THIS
2
3
4 COPY THIS
5 COPY THIS
```

But instead, let's say I would like just COPY. If I visual block select COPY and then `2p` on lines 4 and 5 visual selected

```
1 COPY THIS
2
3
4 COPYCOPY
5
```

How do I paste 1x at each line? Like:

```
1 COPY THIS
2
3
4 COPY
5 COPY
```

Comment: Select the two target lines in line mode (with capital `V`), then it should work

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the register `"` (unnamed) to contain a newline, but at this point its most likely easier to create a new line, paste your content in it and `dd` it again.

```
v
l (or other moving chars to mark the area you want)
y
:let @" = @" . "\n"
2p
```

For further ideas see also [this thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/edit-a-register-td5713747.html).